# spatio-temporal distribution animation. Add time axis for better visualization

Tags: r, lubridate, r-sf, r-sp, tmap

I have added an animation to see spatio-temporal distribution of crashes for a day in region of London.

How can I see the time of crash to better appreciate the animation? A simpler method is to plot crash number and time as text on heading or inside the plot. But thats not desired.

Can someone please help me to create a time axis at the bottom which has points representing each crash and corresponding datetime. Here is an example of desired timeline [link](https://www.ecmindustries.com/en/about/timeline). The point corresponding to the crash changes color in sync with animation below.

[image]

```
install.package("stats19")
library(stat19)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(stats19)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(spData)
library(lubridate)


# crash date of UK
crashes_2019 <- get_stats19(year = 2019, type ="accidents")

# crash data for a day
crashes <- crashes_2019 %>%
  drop_na() %>% 
  filter(date == as_date("2019-01-05")) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)


# creating a polygon 
my_polygon <- cycle_hire %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  st_buffer(dist = 10000) %>%
  st_union()

# open street map of the region
bb <- st_bbox(my_polygon)
osm_map <- read_osm(bb)

# crash inside polygon
crashes_zone <- st_intersection(crashes, 
                                my_polygon)


# animation
m1 <- lapply(seq_along(1:nrow(crashes_zone)), function(point){
  
  x <- crashes_zone[point,]   ## bracketted subsetting to get only 1 point
  
  m1 <- tm_shape(my_polygon) + 
    tm_polygons() + 
  tm_shape(osm_map) + 
    tm_rgb(alpha = 0.6) + 
  tm_shape(x) +  ## single point
    tm_sf(col = 'red', size = 0.1)
})


# Render the animation
tmap_animation(m1, width = 300, height = 600, delay = 100)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you want `gganimate` here? See here https://mikeyharper.uk/animated-plots-with-r/

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that post, I was wondering if we can work around with tmap